# Delphi - TStringList Save/Load to stream encoding

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I'm working with `TStringList` with `TMemeorySteam` a lot in my project.

```
  msTmp := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
     lTemp.SaveToStream(msTmp, TEncoding.Unicode);
  finally
    msTmp.Free;
  end;
  .....
  lTemp := TStringList.Create;
  try
     lTemp.LoadFromFile(msTmp, TEncoding.Unicode);
  finally
    lTemp.Free;
  end;
```

How i can tell the `LoadFromStream()` and `SaveToStream()`   that the stream is UTF-16 encoded by default in my project without including the encoded type in each call.
so i can call `LoadFromStream(msTmp)` only and it will load with UTF-16 encoded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the [`TStrings.DefaultEncoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TStrings.DefaultEncoding) property.

> The default encoding for the current object.
>
> **DefaultEncoding** is used when the nil encoding is specified in a call to `LoadFromStream` or `SaveToStream`.
>
> By default, **DefaultEncoding** is set to `Default`. The user can change **DefaultEncoding** if another default encoding is desired for `LoadFromStream` or `SaveToStream`.

However, watch out for the [`TStrings.Encoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Encoding) property:

> Character encoding determined during reading from a stream or file.
>
> `Encoding` is a read-only property that contains the value of the character encoding detected when the `LoadFromStream` or `LoadFromFile` methods are called. **If a file or stream does not contain a BOM (the encoding value cannot be detected) then `Encoding` is set to the value specified in the `DefaultEncoding` property.**
>
> **`Encoding` is used in the `SaveToStream` and `SaveToFile` methods.**

> If the `Encoding` parameter [of `LoadFromStream`] is not given, then the strings are loaded using the appropriate encoding. The value of the encoding is obtained by calling the `GetBufferEncoding` routine of the `TEncoding` class. **`LoadFromStream` then saves the value of the encoding in the `Encoding` property, to be used if the stream is saved.**

So, as long as you do not call `LoadFrom...()`, you can set `DefaultEncoding` to `TEncoding.Unicode` and then call `SaveTo...()` without specifying a value for the `Encoding` parameter.

But, once you call `LoadFrom...()`, the `Encoding` property takes priority over the `DefaultEncoding` property for subsequent calls to `SaveTo...()`. As long as the files are not BOM'ed, the `Encoding` property will match the `DefaultEncoding` property.  But if a non-UTF16LE BOM is encountered, all bets are off.

To ensure `TEncoding.Unicode` is always used, you should continue using the `Encoding` parameter of `LoadFrom...()` and `SaveTo...()`, that is why they exist.  They take first priority,  the `(Default)Encoding` properties are fallbacks when input/output encodings are not explicitly stated.